# how to force password with passport google oauth in nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, passport-google-oauth

I am currently authenticating my node express application with passport google oauth.
At the moment the application will ask which account to use and then just logs me in.
This is not exact ideal, for example if I use my application at work, which any staff has access to, will then be able to access my application.
Ideally I would like to always enter my password before authentication.

Answer (score 0):

That is not how OAuth works per se. If you wanted strictly password based authentication, then use the passport-local strategy.

If you do not want other people accessing your Express application then either:

1. Do not use a shared computer
2. Use an incognito browser session.

Unless Google's OAuth offers an option to force some sort of password auth, then no. You may have luck browsing around the docs:

https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2